# BMR calculator: Substituting body mass with lean body mass in BMR calculator

Tags: javascript

I modified a body fat calculator using the US navy formula. 
The calculator provides
1. BMR
2. Minimum calorie requirement
3. Body fat

The calculator is working well but i would like the Basal metabolic rate to utilize Lean body mass as opposed to weight (provided in the form)

i added: wt1 = wt-(wt/100*fatPercent) before the BMR calculation.

The console shows no errors but i get no results when i execute the script. Not sure how to correct this.

Thanks in advance

**Javascript code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Calculate()
{
        var ht = parseFloat(document.cal_frm.txtHeight.value);
        var nk = parseFloat(document.cal_frm.txtNeck.value);
        var wa = parseFloat(document.cal_frm.txtWaist.value);
        var hp = parseFloat(document.cal_frm.txtHip.value);
        var wt = parseFloat(document.cal_frm.txtWeight.value);
        var ag = parseInt(document.cal_frm.txtAge.value);
        var sexf=false;
        if (document.cal_frm.opGender.value == "1"){sexf=true;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opHeight.value == "1") {ht = ht * 2.54;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opNeck.value == "1") {nk = nk * 2.54;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opWaist.value == "1") {wa = wa * 2.54;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opHip.value == "1") {hp = hp * 2.54;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opWeight.value == "1") {wt = wt * 0.4536;}
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML='';
        var errors='';
        if ((ht < 122) || (ht > 230) || isNaN(ht)){
        err=((document.cal_frm.opHeight.value == "1")? '48inches to 90inches' : '122cm to 230cm');
errors+='Enter height between '+err+'!n';}
        if ((nk < 10) || (nk > 100) || isNaN(nk)){
        err=((document.cal_frm.opNeck.value == "1")? '6inches to 20inches' : '15cm to 50cm');
errors+='Enter neck between '+err+'!n';}
        if ((wa < 20) || (wa > 200) || isNaN(wa)){
        err=((document.cal_frm.opWaist.value == "1")? '20inches to 80inches' : '50cm to 150cm');
errors+='Enter waist between '+err+'!n';}
        if ((wt < 30) || (wt > 150) || isNaN(wt)){
        err=((document.cal_frm.opWeight.value == "1")? '67lb to 333lb' : '30Kg to 150Kg');
errors+='Enter weight between '+err+'!n';}
        if ((ag < 19) || (ag > 70) || isNaN(ag)){
        err='19yrs to 70yrs';
errors+='Enter age between '+err+'!n';}
        if (sexf==true){
            if ((hp < 50) || (hp > 200) || isNaN(hp)){
            err=((document.cal_frm.opHip.value == "1")? '20inches to 100inches' : '50cm to 250cm');
errors+='Enter hip between '+err+'!n';}}
        if(errors){
            alert('The following error(s) occurred:n'+errors);
            return;}
        var BMR;
        var fatpercent;
        if (sexf==true) {
            fatPercent = 495 / (1.29579 - 0.35004 * (logten(wa + hp - nk)) + 0.221 * (logten(ht))) - 450;   
            wt1 = wt-(wt/100*fatPercent) /*added below code to substitute weight with lean body mass in the below calculation*/
            BMR = 655 + (9.6 * wt1) + (1.8 * ht) - (4.7 * ag);
        }
        else{
            fatPercent = 495 / (1.0324 - 0.19077 * (logten(wa - nk)) + 0.15456 * (logten(ht))) - 450;
            wt1 = wt-(wt/100*fatPercent)/*added below code to substitute weight with lean body mass in the below calculation*/
            BMR = 66 + (13.7 * wt1) + (5 * ht) - (6.8 * ag);
        }
        BMR=Math.round(BMR*10)/10;
        fatPercent = (Math.round(fatPercent*10))/10;
        var dailyCal;
        if (document.cal_frm.opActivity.value == "0") {dailyCal = BMR * 1.2;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opActivity.value == "1") {dailyCal = BMR * 1.375;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opActivity.value == "2") {dailyCal = BMR * 1.55;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opActivity.value == "3") {dailyCal = BMR * 1.725;}
        if (document.cal_frm.opActivity.value == "4") {dailyCal = BMR * 1.9;}

if (document.cal_frm.opWeight.value == "1") { 

        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "<p>Your BMR is: " + BMR + "<br />" + "Minimum Calorie 

requirement is: " + (Math.round(dailyCal)) + ";<br />" + "Your Body Fat is " + fatPercent + "%." + ";<br /></p>";
}
function logten(v){
    return (Math.log(v)/Math.log(10));
}
function resetAll(){
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML ='';
}
}
-->
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<form name="cal_frm" id="cal_frm" style="width:400px; margin:20px 10px 20px 10px;" onsubmit="return false">
<table style="width:400px; margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;">
<tr><td style="width: 275px;">
<table id="cal_data">
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px;">Height:</td>
<td><input class="cal_text" type="text" name="txtHeight" size="20" ></td>
<td><select class="cal_option" name="opHeight">
<option value="0">Cm</option>
<option value="1">Inch</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px;">Neck:</td>
<td><input class="cal_text" type="text" name="txtNeck" size="20" ></td>
<td><select class="cal_option" name="opNeck">
<option value="0">Cm</option>
<option value="1">Inch</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px;">Waist:</td>
<td><input class="cal_text" type="text" name="txtWaist" size="20" ></td>
<td><select class="cal_option" name="opWaist">
<option value="0">Cm</option>
<option value="1">Inch</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px;">Hip (Female):</td>
<td><input class="cal_text" type="text" name="txtHip" size="20" ></td>
<td><select class="cal_option" name="opHip">
<option value="0">Cm</option>
<option value="1">Inch</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5px;">Weight:</td>
<td><input class="cal_text" type="text" name="txtWeight" size="20" ></td>
<td><select class="cal_option" name="opWeight">
<option value="0">Kg</option>
<option value="1">Pound</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td style="padding: 10px 0 0 10px;">
Gender:<br >
<select class="cal_option" style="width:72%;border: solid 1px silver;" name="opGender">
<option value="0">Male</option>
<option value="1">Female</option>
</select><br ><br >
Age:<br >
<input class="cal_text" style="width:60%;border: solid 1px silver;" type="text" name="txtAge" size="20" > yrs.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="padding:10px 0 10px 0;"><span style="padding:0 2px;">Activity:</span>
<select id="Select7" class="cal_option" style="width:80%; border:1px solid silver;" name="opActivity">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Sedentary (Very little or no exercise)</option>
<option value="1">Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/week)</option>
<option value="2">Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week)</option>
<option value="3">Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)</option>
<option value="4">Extra active (very hard exercise/sports & physical job or 2x training)</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="feedback" colspan="2" style="padding:0 0 5px 0; font-family:arial; font-size:11px; color:#333333;" ><a 

style="font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1%;" href="http://ramui.com">http://ramui.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input onclick="Calculate()" class="cal_button" type="button" value="Calculate" >&nbsp;<input type="reset" 

class="cal_button" value="Reset" onclick="resetAll()" ></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output result only if weight is specified in pounds.

Comment: Thanks i didn't realize that. However i still don't understand the problem. Why wouldn't the others work? If kg is selected the value of wt remains the same. If pound is selected, wt is converted to kgs. So what can be done to correct the rest of the script?

Comment: if (document.cal_frm.opWeight.value == "1") { /*Here is the code, that does output*/ }

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to clarify to everyone i added a second conditional statement with option value 0 for kgs   --------    if (document.cal_frm.opWeight.value == "0") { 
        
        document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "<p>Your BMR is: " + BMR + "<br />" + "Minimum Calorie 

requirement is: " + (Math.round(dailyCal)) + ";<br />" + "Your Body Fat is " + fatPercent + "%." + ";<br /></p>";
} ------